# Setting data sessions and array_merge_recursive()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Wondering if anyone can help with the following. Basically I have a form which allows users to select a start and end date, start time and end time.

The user can add time blocks, so they select the info they want, post it, then the page is returned, this happens until they process the form with the complete button.

The issue I am facing is, I need my array to append each post to my array, I have the following code:

```
    if($this->input->post('submit', TRUE) == 'more')
    {
        $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date', TRUE);
        $start_time = $this->input->post('start_time', TRUE);
        $end_time = $this->input->post('end_time', TRUE);

        $start_dates['start_date'] =  $start_date;
        $start_dates['start_time'] =  $start_time;
        $start_dates['end_time'] =  $end_time;


        if(isset($this->session->userdata['start_dates']) )
        {
            $merged = array_merge_recursive($start_dates, $this->session->userdata['start_dates']);
        }
        else
        {
            $merged = null;
            $this->session->set_userdata('start_dates', $start_dates);
        }
```

Problem is, each time we add a new time block one of the items in the array is overwritten.

The expected output for the array is:

```
Array
(
    [start_date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2012-08-31
        [1] => 2012-08-29
    )

    [start_time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08:00
        [1] => 09:00
    )

    [end_time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12:00
        [1] => 17:00
    )

)
```

Array key [1] is always overwritten in this case, if we add only two time blocks this would not be a problem - however the user needs to be able to add more than 2 blocks, total limit is up to user to a set limit we'll specify later.

Could anyone help get the logic sorted out.

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the merged data into the session too and the array merge should apply to the stored array in session:

```
if($this->session->userdata['start_dates'])
{
   $merged = array_merge_recursive($this->session->userdata['start_dates'],
                                   $start_dates);
}
else
{
   $merged = $start_dates;
}
$this->session->set_userdata('start_dates', $merged);
```

Comment: Tried that Yan but it is not saving anything now at all. Kind of stuck, wonder if you could offer some more help into debugging the logic on this for me?

Thanks for your time replying so far.

Comment: @MarkH I slightly modified my answer. Did you destroy the session before trying it?

Comment: Hi Yan, thanks again seems it was a session issue at the top of me trying your solution, appears to work now, may have more questions for you soon :-)

Comment: any reason to switch from array_merge_recursive to array_push? Any performance overheads to be considered?

Comment: After viewing the expected output, array_push won't return the expected result. It will just add a new element at the end of the array. I have edited the answer accordingly.